# How to use string as variable name in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

am having a viewstate which pertains value like:

`string temp;
ViewState["temp"] = dc.ColumnName.ToString();`

This returns weekdays like: `Monday,tuesday,wednesday` etc

Now am using this value here:

```
string a = "txt" + ViewState["temp"].ToString();
TextBox a = new TextBox();
```

But it gives me error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox' to 'string'

I want textbox variable name like `txtmonday,txttuesday` dynamically.
Is there any way that I can assign variable name???

Comment: That does not make any sense. The variable name does not generally affect what code does. Can you explain what you are *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? What is your requirement?

Comment: Also think compile-time vs run-time. Local variable names exist only during compile-time and the values you are trying to use do not exist at compile-time at all since the program has not executed yet.

Comment: if it is to be added at runtime you can have place holder to contian your controls and that manages viewstate. you can do anything here.

Comment: can u elaborate with an example or link vinay?because am new to asp

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. At least not without reflection, and you shouldn't be using reflection here. Variables in C# are a compile-time concept. (Even with reflection, it'll only work for fields, not for local variables.)

If you want a *collection* of values, use a collection... e.g. a `List<T>` or a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. So for example, you could have a `List<TextBox>` (which is accessed by index) or a `Dictionary<string, TextBox>` which is accessed by string key (`"monday"`, `"tuesday"` or whatever you want).

If you're only actually creating a *single* `TextBox`, what does it matter what the variable name is? Just use:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
// Do appropriate things with the TextBox, possibly using ViewState
```

The variable name *just* gives you a way of referring to the variable. That's all it's there for. The *object* you create doesn't know anything about which variables (if any) contain references to it.

Comment: sir,,am actually trying to append this textbox to a gridview,,am adding template field dynamically,so on rowdatabound event,am trying to add this textbox on specified column.for ezample,if a field is generated with headertext MONDAY ,,so it should have txtmonday so as to ease my future gridview manipulations

Comment: @user2177138: But how would know when to use `txtmonday`? If you're going to do things dynamically, that strongly suggests that a collection is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** declare objects at runtime they way you art trying. You can store the week days in array / [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) starting Monday at index `0` and Sunday at index `6`, You can give id of element with the string name you want.

```
List<TextBox> weekList = new List<TextBox>();
weekList.Add(new TextBox());
weekList[0].ID  =  "txt" + ViewState["temp"].ToString();
```