# C#: I am trying to write a method to create a new instance of a class, with a certain ID input as a parameter in the method

Tags: c#

I have created a text adventure thing which loads up a certain type of world file and allows you to play through it, however I am now trying to build a program that allows somebody to actually build one of these worlds. I need to be able to add rooms to this world through this AddRoom() method.

```
    public void AddRoom(String id, String name, String description)
    {
        Room id = new Room(name, description);
    }
    AddRoom("kitchen1", "Old Kitchen", "A dark, cold, old kitchen");
```

This should  create:

```
Room kitchen1;
```

But of course I can't have the ID of a room being a string, how would I go about changing the AddRoom method so that I was able to determine the name of the room in the parameters.

Comment: It is not totally clear what you would like to achieve; does the `Room` clas have a member to store some id?

Comment: Sorry, I am quite sick and not thinking 100% straight right now. My english and wording is probably a bit off. By ID, I mean to create a room variable,
Room kitchen1;
kitchen1 is the ID

Comment: I rewrote a muck type system in c# it actually went fairly easy. its usual in these senses that ID is a UID, so would be an integer number. when you add a room, you dont give it a number, it picks an available one and returns you what ID it used.

Comment: How would one go about achieving that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use string as variable name in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904787/how-to-use-string-as-variable-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you want to "add variables at runtime", chances are you're just looking for a `Dictionary<string, Room>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionnary for this. Here's an example:

```
Dictionary<string, Room> rooms = new Dictionary<string, Room>();
```

this will create a Dictionary where the key is the Room ID (ex: "kitchen1") and the value is the `Room` object and in your `AddRoom` method you can use it like this:

```
public void AddRoom(String id, String name, String description)
{
    // Note that the rooms variable must be accessible inside your method
    rooms.Add(id, new Room(name, description));
}
```

and then later your access the room using its id like this:

```
rooms["kitchen1"].Name // Or whatever variable the name is stored in
rooms["kitchen1"].Description // Or whatever variable the Description is stored in
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public struct Room
    {
        public String Name;
        public String Desc;
    }
    Dictionary<string, Room> World = new Dictionary<string, Room>();
    public void AddRoom(String id, String name, String description)
    {
        Room room = new Room() { Name = name, Desc = description };
        World.Add(id, room);
    }

AddRoom("kitchen1", "Old Kitchen", "A dark, cold, old kitchen");
```

Now to Fetch detail of kitchen1 from world

```
Room kitchen = World["kitchen1"];
kitchen.Name  //will give name
kitchen.Desc  //will give Description of kitchen
```